# Related tables in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Feeling it's a dumb question but how does one diagram the relationship for the following tables:

Table **Vehicle**:

```
VehicleId
VehicleName
ConditionId
SeverityId
```

Table **Conditions**:

```
ConditionId
ConditionName
```

Table **Severity**:

```
SeverityId
ConditionId
SeverityName
```

Conditions have multiple potential severities but a vehicle can only have 1 condition which has 1 severity.

For some reason I can't wrap my head around the table and diagram design.

Edit: It will create the diagram but not constrain entered data on table **Vehicle** (conditions)

[image: As per the above diagram]

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Based on what you describe, the table layout you have will work.  If you want to diagram it, SSMS has diagraming tools built in. Just expand the database you want to work with, right click on Database Diagrams and create your tables.

Comment: There are different types of diagrams one can use for modelling, for simplicity I personally find `Chen`-Style pretty easy to grasp, see for example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ERD_Representation.svg

Answer (score 0):

Umm...sorry about that stupidity folks. Warm day here. Just removed the constraint between ConditionTypes and VehicleConditions.